# how IEEE-754 floating point numbers work

Tags: types, floating-point, ieee-754

Let's say I have this:

```
float i = 1.5
```

in binary, this float is represented as:

0 01111111 10000000000000000000000

I broke up the binary to represent the 'signed', 'exponent' and 'fraction' chunks.

What I don't understand is how this represents 1.5.

The exponent is 0 once you subtract the bias (127 - 127), and the fraction part with the implicit leading one is 1.1.

How does 1.1 scaled by nothing = 1.5???

Comment: You mean "sign," "exponent" and "significand."

Comment: hah i wasn't meaning to use the technical terms. just what they represent :)

Comment: title of the question should rather be "how to understand floating point numbers in binary" or something like that - it is actually not related to C

Comment: Updated title to reflect the fact that C doesn't pin down the encoding at all, and that hatorade is really asking about the IEEE-754 format.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Think first in terms of decimal (base 10): 643.72 is:

- (6 * 10<sup>2</sup>) +
- (4 * 10<sup>1</sup>) +
- (3 * 10<sup>0</sup>) +
- (7 * 10<sup>-1</sup>) +
- (2 * 10<sup>-2</sup>)

or 600 + 40 + 3 + 7/10 + 2/100.

That's because n<sup>0</sup> is always 1, n<sup>-1</sup> is the same as 1/n (for a specific case) and n<sup>-m</sup> is identical to 1/n<sup>m</sup> (for  more general case).

Similarly, the binary number 1.1 is:

- (1 * 2<sup>0</sup>) +
- (1 * 2<sup>-1</sup>)

with 2<sup>0</sup> being one and 2<sup>-1</sup> being one-half.

In decimal, the numbers to the left of the decimal point have multipliers 1, 10, 100 and so on heading left from the decimal point, and 1/10, 1/100, 1/1000 heading right (i.e., 10<sup>2</sup>, 10<sup>1</sup>, 10<sup>0</sup>, decimal point, 10<sup>-1</sup>, 10<sup>-2</sup>, ...).

In base-2, the numbers to the left of the binary point have multipliers 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and so on heading left. The numbers to the right have multipliers 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 and so on heading right.

So, for example, the binary number:

```
101.00101
| |   | |
| |   | +- 1/32
| |   +---  1/8
| +-------    1
+---------    4
```

is equivalent to:

```
4 + 1 + 1/8 + 1/32
```

or:

```
    5
5  --
   32
```

Answer (score 7):

1.1 in binary is 1 + .5 = 1.5

Answer (score 1):

The mantissa is essentially shifted by the exponent.

```
3 in binary is 0011
3>>1 in binary, equal to 3/2, is 0001.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to read this - [IEEE 754-1985](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

The actual standard is [here](http://standards.ieee.org/reading/ieee/std_public/description/busarch/754-1985_desc.html)

Comment: The actual pdfs of all these standards can usually be found by a Google search…

Comment: The wikipedia page isn't the standard, and shouldn't be used as such.  That's (I think) Potatoswatter's point.

Comment: Added IEEE site to actual standard - The first site explains it in more layman terms.

Comment: My point was also that they can be found for free. I thought about providing a link but that would probably be unwise :v( .